# How to create a customized log monitoring job in java which provide reports of exception message happened on log file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j, spring-batch

1. Should able to process larger log files and provide exception message reports
2. After completion of log analysis, report notification trigger to specific mail id's.
   And also please suggest which framework is the best for processing large files.[eg: spring boot/batch]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack). Stream the logs to elastic search and set up alerts in Kibana.

Comment: I am expecting customized code, because in my project not able to use any tools

Answer (score 0):

Can use sendmail client on system and run script on that system to send alert on any Exception.

```
exception="Exception" # "Error", "HTTP 1.1 \" 500", etc
ignoredException="ValidationException"

# log file to scan 
logFileToScan=/var/log/tomcat8/log/application.log

# file where we will keep log of this script
logFilePath=/home/ec2-user/exception.log

# a file where we store till what line the log file has been scanned
# initalize it with 0 
countPath=/home/ec2-user/lineCount

# subject with which you want to receive the mail regading Exception
subject="[ALERT] Exception"

# from whom do you want to send the mail regarding Exception
from="abc@abc.com"

# to whom do you want to send the mail
to="xyz@xyz.com"

# number of lines, before the line containing the word to be scanned, to be sent in the mail
linesBefore=1

# number of lines, before the line containing the word to be scanned, to be sent in the mail
linesAfter=4

# start line
fromLine=`cat $countPath`

# current line count in the file
toLine=`wc -l $logFileToScan | awk '{print $1}'`

#logs are rolling so if fromLine has a value greater than toLine then fromLine has to be set to 0
if [ "$fromLine" == "" ]; then
        fromLine=0
        echo `date` fromLine values was empty, set to 0 >> $logFilePath
elif [ $fromLine -gt $toLine ]; then
        echo `date` logfile was rolled, updating fromLine from $fromLine to 0 >> $logFilePath
        fromLine=0
fi

# if from n to lines are equal then no logs has been generated since last scan
if [ "$fromLine" == "$toLine" ]; then
        echo `date` no logs genetared after last scan >> $logFilePath
else
        echo `date` updating linecount to $toLine >> $logFilePath
        echo $toLine > $countPath

        logContent=`tail -n +"$fromLine" $logFileToScan | head -n "$((toLine - fromLine))" | grep -v $ignoredException | grep -A $linesAfter -B $linesBefore $exception`
        logContent=`echo $logContent | cut -c1-2000`
        if [ "$logContent" == "" ]; then
                echo `date` no exception found >> $logFilePath
                else
                /usr/sbin/sendmail $to <<EOF
subject: $subject
from: $from

logContent=$logContent

EOF
        fi
fi
```